# slackware -- get back to the installation menu

Tags: software-installation, package-management, slackware

I booted my new computer with a Slackware 14.2 DVD, ran the built-in `setup` program, and installed enough packages (A, L, N) to at least get machine running and on my network.

Now that the machine is running, I'd like to get back to that very nice menu-based installation program, where I can see a huge list of all of the packages available in the "AP" set and choose which ones I do/don't want to install, and set them up to install while I go have lunch.

But I can't find it.  I see the `pkgtool` program that will ask me individually to install each package and individually demand an answer yes or no.  But I can't find the `setup` program that gave me the menus.

Does anybody know what it's called and/or where I can find it or download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit later, but I know the answer, and what you're looking for is the command `slackpkg`, use it this way:

```
# slackpkg install ap
```

`slackpkg` is the official packages' installer for slackware. This utility needs to be configured basically to specify the mirror to use when installing, upgrading packages.

But, you need to add this package to your minimal installation set, it is located in the `ap` series.

So I suggest the following procedure:

1) Begin the installation and select your minimal setup.

2) Wait for it to finish

3) Login and mount the slackware boot disk

```
# mount /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom
```

4) Install the `slackpkg` package by using `installpkg` (this utility is included in the `pkgtools` package which belongs to the `a` series)

```
# installpkg /media/cdrom/slackware/ap/slackpkg-2.82.1-noarch-3.txz
```

5) Edit the `/etc/slackpkg/mirrors` file and uncomment the entry `cdrom://media/cdrom/`

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Local CD/DVD drive
#----------------------------------------------------------------
cdrom://media/cdrom/
#
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Local Directory
```

6) run `slackpkg update` to update the installation sources

7) use `slackpkg install ap` to choose which packages to install from the `ap` series

8) Select the desired packages

9) Go to have lunch

Comment: It doesn't have the one-line descriptions that the installation menu has, but this is close enough to what I want/need.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't do much on the system yet, then maybe you could just take a little extra time to re-install everything, including the optional packages. Since the OS installer is usually a DVD-only thing, you can't just use it magically post-installation.

I have also another idea, but I have no idea if it could work. You could start the installer again and skip all installation stages except the packaging one, so you can just add the packages you need right now.

Comment: The goal was to do this without rebooting, while the machine is awake and running and on the network.  But if it's a DVD-only thing, then I guess I'm out of luck.  Thanks.  I'll accept your answer in a couple of days if nobody contradicts you.